# Rational number denominator

Tags: arguments

```
public Rational(long numerator, long denominator) {
long gcd = gcd(numerator, denominator);
this.numerator = ((denominator > 0) ? 1 : -1) * numerator / gcd;
this.denominator = Math.abs(denominator) / gcd;
```

Hello I'm wondering about the 3rd line where it says ((denominator > 0) ? 1 : -1) * numerator / gcd.  What is the argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This format:

```
x = denominator > 0 ? 1 : -1
```

Is similar to an `if` statement.

If denominator is greater than zero x will be set to 1
otherwise x will be set to -1

A more generalized form would be

```
 ? __ : __
```

This form of expression is in several languages such as C, Java, Swift, Objective C, ...